# Why does SVG path curve get filled?

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG `path` element:

```
<path id="SvgjsPath1012" d="M97 267C100 106 400 100 400 250 "></path>
```

It draws a nice Bezier curve for me, but the shape is filled. It thinks the curve is meant to be a closed polygon. So connects the end vertices of the curve with a straight line and fills the whole closed shape.

All I wanted was a thin "line" curve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paths default to a `fill` value of black and a `stroke` value of none.  Change the `stroke` and set the `fill` to "none" using either css or inline attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/ehnzxg00/

Inline:

```
<path id="SvgjsPath1012" d="M97 267C100 106 400 100 400 250" stroke="red" fill="none"></path>
```

CSS:

```
#SvgjsPath1012{
    fill: none;
    stroke: purple;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

---

Additional information:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes